# How to generate a stacked histogram from different sized matrices?

Tags: matlab, histogram

I have two matrices with different size, one is `3000 x 1` other one is `6000 x 1`. I want to plot a stacked histogram from these matrices. That's code I tried so far:

```
hist(S1,20);
hold on
hist(S,20)
h = findobj(gca,'Type','patch');
display(h) 
set(h(1),'FaceColor',[0 0 0],'EdgeColor',[1 1 1],'facealpha',1.0);
set(h(2),'FaceColor',[1 1 1],'EdgeColor',[0 0 0],'facealpha',.3);
```

At the end, the plot would be like this which is not stacked:

[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can i make it stacked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB's [`bar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html) method has a [`'stacked'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bar.html#bthxce9) option. It's irrelevant, if your arrays have different sizes or varying value ranges, as long as the histograms you create have the same x-values. You can achieve that by properly setting the [`xbins`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hist.html#d118e588228) parameter.

Here's a small example:

```matlab
S1 = randi([-8 8], 30, 1);
S2 = randi([-10 10], 60, 1);

hist_range = -10:10;

h1 = hist(S1, hist_range)
h2 = hist(S2, hist_range)

figure(1);
bar(hist_range, [h1(:), h2(:)], 'stacked')
xlim([-11 11]);
legend('h1', 'h2');
```

Examplary output (Octave 5.1.0, code also tested with MATLAB Online):

```
h1 =
   0   0   2   2   3   1   1   0   3   1   3   2   2   0   1   2   3   1   3   0   0

h2 =
   2   2   2   0   4   5   0   2   3   2   5   3   0   6   3   6   2   5   1   5   2
```

[image: Output]

Hope that helps!

Comment: In case you have problems choosing `hist_range` you can also let `hist` do it: `[~,hist_range]=hist([S1;S2])`